# Can I use two arrays of pointers to struct, pointing to the same struct?

Tags: arrays, c, struct

I am taking my first steps in playing with pointers and structs, and I was doing this work for my school that tells me to order this array of pointers pointing to a struct according to title. That's all set and done and I want to ask if I can do this code.

```
typedef struct book {
    char title[MAX_TITLE];
    char isbn[MAX_ISBN];
    char authors[MAX_AUTHORS];
    char publisher[MAX_PUB_NAME];
} Book;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
if(argc < 2)
    {
        printf("error. insert a file or a valid one when compiling\n");
        return 0;
    }
    
    FILE* src = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    
    if(src == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nERROR.Insert valid file or file name\n");
        return 0;
    }
    
    Book lista_T[MAX_BOOKS];
    Book lista_I[MAX_BOOKS];
    
    int bookCount = loadList(lista_T,MAX_BOOKS,src);
    int bookCount = loadList(lista_I,MAX_BOOKS,src);
```

They tell me I have to create another list array of pointers to the struct and sort it this time by the array isbn which contains a code specific to each book but not changing the sorting by title that I made for lista_T.

I initially thought I could walk right in and make an array lista_I with the same parameters and sort that one through the array isbn while not touching on the other array which is sorted by title. But when I went to compile it and tried to print all the information ordered on both arrays of struct lista_T and lista_I, I realized that Lista_T printed everything correctly but lista_I did not print anything, like there is nothing there. Why did this happen.
sorry if I'm making some obvious mistake here but as I was saying, this my first work using pointers and stuff related.

Tell me if there's parts of the code that you need to see that I didn't put here in order to help further.

P.S. the teachers in this work told specifically not to use malloc or other stuff like that and simply pre-allocate oversized memory allocation to make things simpler for me at the start.

Comment: "to order this array of pointers" You should first start to use an array of pointers to solve the first part of your task before you continue with the second part.

Answer (score 0):

From your description of the behavior, I infer that the function
`loadList` simply starts reading at the whatever position in the input file
is indicated by `src`, and keeps reading data until it reaches a stopping condition
of some sort (perhaps having read data for `MAX_BOOKS` books, perhaps reaching the end of the file, perhaps either of those, whichever comes first).
After it stops reading books, it stops doing anything with `src`.

So when the function `loadList` is called for the second time, `src` points to a file accessor that is positioned after the end of the last data read by the first call,
and there are no more books after that point.
So there is no data to read from the file and nothing to put in the array.

There is no reason to read the data from a file twice. You can use `src`, which accesses the file, to read the data the first time, but when you need a second array you should only be looking at data already read from the file.
You should not refer to `src` at all.

(Technically, you could rewind the file and then you would be able to read the data all over again, but reading files is relatively expensive--why would you read the same file twice in a row?)

By the way, you don't have any arrays of pointers to a struct in the code in the question. You have two arrays of structs.
An array of pointers to a struct would look something like this:

```
    Book* lista_I[MAX_BOOKS];
```

Comment: Sorry for the mess up on that, they really are arrays of structs not array of pointers. You where incredibly correct on that src pointing to the end of my text. And as you said i didn't had to read again from the file, i simply used the function memcpy to copy from one to another, just had to pass the size of lista_T(using sizeof) and from there on i sorted my array lista_I from isbn and finally i was able to apply the bsearch function(that's why i had to sort my array). Thank you very much once again.